# Encrypt Or Hide QueryString at Asp.net website using .net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, encryption, query-string

I have an existing asp.net web site built with master pages and what I need to hide or encrypt all pass query strings values in a common place without changing a lot of code.

Can any one help me with this please .. or is there another idea instead of hiding or encrypting >>?

Thanks.

Comment: What level of obfuscation do you need? Query string params will always visible in one form or another unless they are eliminated completely.

Comment: I need to obfuscate all query strings values that I pass between pages for a security reason.

Answer (score 7):

What Chris said in his answer is absolutely correct. I would accept that as the answer if it is suitable.

The first question is, do you *need* to use a query string if you are hiding it from the user? Perhaps something like [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) is better to avoid the user from ever seeing it in the first place.

However, barring that - perhaps you have a requirement that you can't work around and you absolutely have to do it yourself using the query string.

You can encrypt the query string, in your case I would use [DPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_protection_API) so you don't have to worry about troublesome things like key management. Here is an example usage:

```
    public static string Encrypt(string val)
    {
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val);
        var encBytes = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(bytes, new byte[0], System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encBytes);
    }


    public static string Decrypt(string val)
    {
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(val);
        var encBytes = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(bytes, new byte[0], System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encBytes);
    }
```

You would have to add a reference to the `System.Security` assembly and import the namespace `System.Security.Cryptography`.

Here's an example on how to use it in a page:

```
Response.Redirect("~/somepage.aspx?data=" + Server.UrlEncode(Encrypt("SomeSensitiveData")));
```

And to decrypt it:

```
var data = Decrypt(Request.QueryString["data"]);
```

You can use this to encrypt a query string value, such as `Encrypt` and use `Decrypt` on the page that needs to interpret the query string.

You can use this in addition to SSL; which is a good idea. This will also mean that the user won't be able to see the query string values.

There are caveats to using DPAPI. One is that it doesn't play well with load balancers. You would have to use something else, or setup the load balancer to use a sticky session. Another is that if they bookmark a page with an encrypted query string value; and you moved to another server, then all of the bookmarks will contain encrypted query strings that the server cannot decrypt now.

If the query strings need to be preserved (such as for bookmarking), and it isn't for just "temporary" use, then you would need to come up with a common key, keep it somewhere safe, and do the encryption yourself with something like AES.

Comment: I think u don't get my point .. I already have the code written before and I want to do the hiding or the encryption in a common place so I don't need to rewrite the code and find every place that sending querystring.

Comment: @AmrElnashar You are going to have to change some code. There is no silver bullet in this case. You *could* do something silly like write an HTTP Module for IIS; or see if a commercial option is available.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you want to encrypt the query string?  If you are trying to send sensitive information from the browser to the server, use SSL.  If you try to encrypt it yourself, you are bound to fail in some subtle way.  Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Encryption is not the best solution I know that but is there another solution to hide the data sent between pages.

Comment: Who are you trying to hide it from?  The user of the browser?  Or some other entity (e.g. a hacker, man in the middle, government entity, etc)?

Comment: If you just want to hide it from the user, why not just use POST requests, instead of GETs?  Alternatively, you can use a URL rewriter: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: I'd also add that if your intent is to prevent the user from doing something malicious (e.g. changing the querystring from ?userid=myaccount to ?userid=youraccount), then you should use a Session variable as @vcsjones mentions.  No amount of security based on obfuscation is going to prevent a malicious user from breaking it.

Comment: Chris please do u have an example for the session solution ..

Comment: Plenty of examples in the link that @vcsjones provided.